# Objective-C NSUserDefaults cannot store my info

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I tried many times to store my info using `NSUserDefaults` but failed. I don't know how to solve.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (tableView == mySearchController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        //BMKPoiInfo* info = poiResultArray[indexPath.row];
        NSString *nn = poiResultArray[indexPath.row];

    //dw
    NSUserDefaults *userDef =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDef setInteger:1 forKey:@"poiPosition"];
//        [userDef setObject:@"aa" forKey:@"poiPosition"];
    [userDef synchronize];

    [_selectBtn setTitle:nn/*info.name*/ forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSInteger nu = [userDef integerForKey:@"poiPosition"];
```

these are my codes , but "nu" has no result,and u can see I had

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDef setInteger:1 forKey:@"poiPosition"];
//        [userDef setObject:@"aa" forKey:@"poiPosition"];
    [userDef synchronize];
```

why "nu" has nothing?

Comment: What exactly are you getting for an error, and how does recieved output differ from expected output? Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for information on how to revise your post.

Comment: What's the purpose to read the defaults value back in the same scope right after saving it? At this moment the value is supposed to be well-known.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code man. Check spell of key which you using in your code if you entering different. here it's seems perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use -`[NSUserDefaults setInteger:forKey:]` to store the value and -`[NSUserDefaults integerForKey]` to retrieve it.

make sure you are using same key for save and retrieve object from `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: yes,key is the same,u can see code in the question content

Comment: NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"poiPosition"]);  and this is working for me